# Scrap para enlaces internos con BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, scraping, beautifulsoup

Planteando una clase para obtener todos los enlaces internos de una página, ¿qué regla habría que utilizar para distinguir los enlaces internos respecto a los externos como puede ser enlaces a redes sociales?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urlparse

class Crawler():
    def __init__(self, url, limit):
        self.page = url
        url_parse = urlparse(url)
        self.domain = url_parse.netloc
        self.scheme = url_parse.scheme
        name_company = url_parse.netloc.split('.')
        self.company = name_company[len(name_company)-2]
        self.limit = limit
        self.links = list()
        self.ssnn = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'instagram', 'pinterest', 'youtube', 'vimeo', 'google']

    def getLinks(self):
        page = requests.get(self.page)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
        links_page = soup.find_all('a',href=True)

        try:
            total = 1
            for l in links_page:
                if (len(self.links) == self.limit):
                    break

                url_link = l['href']
                info_link = urlparse(url_link)
                domain_link = info_link.netloc
                
                if 'tel' not in url_link and 'mailto' not in url_link:
                    if self.domain == domain_link:
                        if url_link not in self.links:
                            self.links.append(url_link)
                    else:
                        if not any(rrss in url_link for rrss in self.ssnn):
                            complete_link = self.scheme + '://' + self.domain + '/' + url_link
                            if (complete_link not in self.links):
                                self.links.append(complete_link)
                        
                            
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Error: ", ex, " -> ", url_link)


    def run(self):
        for link in self.links:
            self.page = link
            self.getLinks()
```

Veo que alguna web, existen enlaces del tipo href="/yyyy/yyyy.html" pero también puede ser de la forma href="yyyy/yyyy.html", con lo que no puedo sacar el dominio del enlace y no veo que sea muy aconsejable crear una lista con las redes sociales, en este caso la propiedad ssnn de la clase para hacer la comparación.
¿Alguna idea para optimizar esta clase?

Comment: A los que son "yyyy/yyyy.html" puedes revisar si el primer caracter es "/", si es así agregas el dominio al principio, y si no, agregas la barra y después el dominio.

Comment: Ok, pero si por ejemplo es un enlace del tipo https://www.facebook.com/empresa como puedo saberlo, sin tener una comprobación en la lista donde tengo las redes sociales, por no tener una lista con todas las posibilidades que no quiero.